# CSS семейное дерево

Tags: html, css

Есть замечательное решение с семейным древом [на CodePen](https://codepen.io/P233/pen/Kzbsi/).

Но если в ячейке более одной строки, то они накладываются друг на друга снизу, а верхняя часть остается фиксированной. Как можно это поправить?

[image: скрин проблемы]

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 50px;
  color: #eee9dc;
  font: 16px Verdana, sans-serif;
  background: #2e6ba7;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.branch {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 250px;
}
.branch:before {
  content: "";
  width: 50px;
  border-top: 2px solid #eee9dc;
  position: absolute;
  left: -100px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 1px;
}

.entry {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 60px;
}
.entry:before {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 2px solid #eee9dc;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
}
.entry:after {
  content: "";
  width: 50px;
  border-top: 2px solid #eee9dc;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 1px;
}
.entry:first-child:before {
  width: 10px;
  height: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 2px;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
}
.entry:first-child:after {
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
}
.entry:last-child:before {
  width: 10px;
  height: 50%;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
}
.entry:last-child:after {
  height: 10px;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #eee9dc;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
  margin-top: -9px;
}
.entry.sole:before {
  display: none;
}
.entry.sole:after {
  width: 50px;
  height: 0;
  margin-top: 1px;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.label {
  display: block;
  min-width: 150px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #eee9dc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -15px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="wrapper"><span class="label">Root</span>
  <div class="branch lv1">
    <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-1<br>
 232332<br>
 wewewe<br>
 srer
 </span>
      <div class="branch lv2">
        <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-1-1</span>
          <div class="branch lv3">
            <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-1-1-1</span></div>
   <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-1-2-1</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-1-2</span>
          <div class="branch lv3">
            <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-1-2-1</span></div>
   <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-1-2-1</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-2</span>
      <div class="branch lv2">
        <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-3</span>
          <div class="branch lv3">
            <div class="entry"><span class="label"><span>Entry-1</span></br>
 <span>232332</span></br>
 <span>wewewe</span></br>
 <span>srer</span></br></span></div>
            <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-1<br>
 232332<br>
 wewewe<br>
 srer</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-1<br>
 232332<br>
 wewewe<br>
 srer</span>
  <div class="branch lv3">
            <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-3-2</span>
            </div>
            <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-3-3</span></div>
          </div>
  </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Задать высоту ячеек больше, например `.entry {   min-height: 100px; }`

Answer (score 1):

Блоки с текстом `.label` позиционированы абсолютно, а родительский блок `.entry` растягивается блоком с потомками (`.branch`). Но когда потомки не указаны, высота `.entry` остаётся прежней, и многострочный `.label` выходит за его пределы.

Чтобы поправить дело, можно, например, добавить класс всем последним `.branch` и с помощью этого класса переопределить стили для `.label`.

```
.branch.open .label {
  margin-top: 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

К сожалению, если добавить просвет между соседними `.label`, то появляются разрывы в линиях. Насколько понимаю, нужно править свойства для псевдоэлементов, которые их задают. Это уже сами.

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 50px;
  color: #eee9dc;
  font: 16px Verdana, sans-serif;
  background: #2e6ba7;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.branch {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 250px;
}
.branch:before {
  content: "";
  width: 50px;
  border-top: 2px solid #eee9dc;
  position: absolute;
  left: -100px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 1px;
}

.entry {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 60px;
}
.entry:before {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 2px solid #eee9dc;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
}
.entry:after {
  content: "";
  width: 50px;
  border-top: 2px solid #eee9dc;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 1px;
}
.entry:first-child:before {
  width: 10px;
  height: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 2px;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
}
.entry:first-child:after {
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
}
.entry:last-child:before {
  width: 10px;
  height: 50%;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
}
.entry:last-child:after {
  height: 10px;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #eee9dc;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
  margin-top: -9px;
}
.entry.sole:before {
  display: none;
}
.entry.sole:after {
  width: 50px;
  height: 0;
  margin-top: 1px;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.label {
  display: block;
  min-width: 150px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #eee9dc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -15px;
}
.branch.open .label {
  margin-top: 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="wrapper"><span class="label">Root</span>
  <div class="branch lv1">
    <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-1<br>
 232332<br>
 wewewe<br>
 srer
 </span>
      <div class="branch lv2">
        <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-1-1</span>
          <div class="branch lv3">
            <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-1-1-1</span></div>
   <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-1-2-1</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-1-2</span>
          <div class="branch lv3">
            <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-1-2-1</span></div>
   <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-1-2-1</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-2</span>
      <div class="branch lv2">
        <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-3</span>
          <div class="branch lv3 open">
            <div class="entry"><span class="label"><span>Entry-1</span></br>
 <span>232332</span></br>
 <span>wewewe</span></br>
 <span>srer</span></br></span></div>
            <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-1<br>
 232332<br>
 wewewe<br>
 srer</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-1<br>
 232332<br>
 wewewe<br>
 srer</span>
  <div class="branch lv3">
            <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-3-2</span>
            </div>
            <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-3-3</span></div>
          </div>
  </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```